# MS Project Server 2013 project resources page give unknown error?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, ms-project

I have MS Project Server 2013 Integrated with SharePoint 2013

I create one project web app site, and when I want to access resource link

it loads and loads after that it gives error like this:

```
An unknown error has occurred
```

can any one tell me what cause this problem

Answer (score 0):

First, enable displaying the exact error message on the server as described [here](https://marcellotonarelli.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/sharepoint-web-config-how-to-show-full-errors/).

Next, see the ULS logs (`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS`) for error details.

Comment: It does not give error in the ULS log here is a solution for project server 2010  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brismith/archive/2010/07/02/project-server-2010-an-unknown-error-has-occurred-in-project-center-resource-center-or-tasks.aspx but for me all the settings mentioned on the post is ok but don't know why it is not working

Comment: And there is no related error in the Windows Event Log (Application) as well? Have you checked the comments too for further possibilities?